# Any impact of doing dynamic module loading using __import__?

Tags: python, import

In my application, I have:

```
...
folder_a/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    folder_b/
        __init__.py
        b1.py 
        b2.py
        ...
```

and I need to dynamically load modules from `folder_b` into `a.py`, based on an variable, say, `module_from_b`. To do this, in `a.py`, I do:

```
mymodule = __import__("folder_b.%s" % module_from_b, globals(), locals(), fromlist=["*"])
```

Since this is going to live inside a loop, i.e. be called numerous times, I wonder if it has any impact on the performance, or anything else? If so, is there any way to mitigate it while preserving the capability of dynamic module loading?

Comment: the `import` keyword does use the `__import__` function

Comment: @JBernardo, so even with numerous imports (switching back band forth between modules) in a loop, it's not too much of a performance issue?

Comment: If a module is already loaded, it will not be loaded again, if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never benchmarked it, but I believe importing (whether dynamic or static) a module that has been previously imported into the running interpreter (even by completely unrelated code) should be pretty cheap. All it really has to do should be some (successful) dictionary lookups.

Importing a new module will of course run all the code in the module, plus the file system search to find it.

So if you're repeatedly importing a dynamically chosen module from a relatively small set of modules, then you shouldn't have much of a problem so long as you can tolerate a delay the first time each specific module is used (how much of a delay depends on your modules); after a little while almost all of the modules you're importing will already have been imported, and so the `__import__` calls will become cheap.

An alternative design you might consider: If the total set of modules you'll need is knowable up front (either statically or dynamically), you could pre-import them before your loop to "warm up" Python's imported module set. If there aren't many modules in b that won't be used you could import everything in b's `__init__.py`.

That way the import delays would be gotten out of the way at initiation time and you could use `getattr` on the b package to dynamically get your modules instead of needing to use `__import__`. Not such a good option if you're loading so many modules that you *want* to spread out the import costs over your loop, or if you have many modules but only need a relatively small number of them and it's hard to know which ones ahead of time.

There's another possibly even better approach, which will work if in the places where you're identifying which module to import you're choosing some constant string (and not, say, something read from a configuration file or user input). Rather than passing the name of the module onwards to eventually be imported elsewhere, why not import the module then and there and pass the **module itself** on to eventually be used elsewhere? As a made up example, since I don't know what you're doing, instead of:

```
for module_name in ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']:
    function_using_module(module_name)

def function_using_module(module_name):
    module = __import__(...)
    ...
```

You could do:

```
from folder_b import b1, b2, b3, b4

for module in [b1, b2, b3, b4]:
    function_using_module(module)

def function_using_module(module):
    ...
```

Modules are objects just like anything else, so you can store them in lists or objects or whatever you're doing with the names. Passing the modules around directly is usually cleaner than passing the names around as proxies for the modules and later importing them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I don't quite get what you've proposed in the last paragraph. Could you elaborate it a bit more maybe with an example? Also, for your 'warm-up' approach, can I just import everything in package `b` at the beginning of module `a.py`, so that when I later call `__import__` in the loop all those modules are already loaded. P.S. All the modules in `b` will be needed.

Comment: 1. I've added a bit more to my suggestion of passing modules around rather than names. 2. Yes, importing everything at the beginning of `a.py` would give you the "warm up" effect; but it would also give you the module objects to pass around instead of the names, as in my example, and then you no longer need `__import__` at all. I've been programming in Python for years, and I've used dynamically chosen modules several times before, but I've *never* needed `__import__`.

Answer (score 0):

It makes absolutely no difference import statements are represented as calls to `__import__()` in bytecode. The following two are [equivalent](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).

```
import spam
spam = __import__('spam', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to potentially be doing it numerous times, why not just check if that module already exists in your current namespace and if not only then import it.

```
if 'module_I_need_to_load' not in dir():
    from b import module_I_need_to_load
# Or you can look in vars() instead if you have a
# hell of a lot of modules loaded up as dir is a 
# list and vars is a dictionary which will have a
# faster lookup time when you start having a lot of
# elements
if 'module_I_need_to_load' not in vars():
    from b import module_I_need_to_load
```

Comment: -1 Python's import mechanism already does this. It's pointless to check to see whether a module has already been imported then conditionally call `__import__`, only to have `__import__` check whether the module exists and conditionally run the actual import mechanism.